# Função em js que esconda e mostre divs independentes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou montando um Quiz onde cada click leva o usuário a uma parte do Quiz. Tudo é carregado na mesma página para não ficar pulando entre páginas. Cada slide esta contido na sua própria `div` e dentro deles os botões que levam a outros slides.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como reage:
quando no *main slide*  eu clico no link que leva para o slide1 o *main slide* é escondido e o slide1 entra no lugar (utilizando hide and show css) e assim por diante, quando no slide1 clico para ir pro slide1-1 o slide1 é escondido e o slide1-1 aparece.

Gostaria de uma função em JavaScript  que fizesse isso. Já procurei no fórum mas não consegui implementar para que funcionasse direto. Tenho pouco conhecimento em JavaScript mas compreendo bem lógica.

Este é um html teste que estou utilizando

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">MAIN
      <a href="#">slide1</a>
      <a href="#">slide2</a>
    </div>
    <!-- second layer -->
    <div class="slide1>SLIDE1
      <a href="#">slide1-1</a>
      <a href="#">slide1-2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">SLIDE2
      <a href="#">slide2-1</a>
      <a href="#">slide2-2</a>
    </div>
    <!-- third layer -->
    <div class="slide1-1">SLIDE1-1</div>
    <div class="slide1-2">SLIDE1-2</div>
    <div class="slide2-1">SLIDE2-1</div>
    <div class="slide2-2">SLIDE2-2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma solução com função genérica e jQuery:

```js
$('[data-target]').on('click', function(e) {
  
  // Evitar o click padrão do botão (href)
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Esconde todos slides visíveis
  $('.slide:visible').hide();
  
  // Exibe o slide configurado no data-target
  $($(this).data('target')).show();
  
});
```

```css
.slide {
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="slide main">MAIN
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide1">slide1</a>
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide2">slide2</a>
    </div>
    <!-- second layer -->
    <div class="slide slide1">SLIDE1
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide1-1">slide1-1</a>
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide1-2">slide1-2</a>
      <a href="#" data-target=".main">voltar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">SLIDE2
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide2-1">slide2-1</a>
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide2-2">slide2-2</a>
      <a href="#" data-target=".main">voltar</a>
    </div>
    <!-- third layer -->
    <div class="slide slide1-1">SLIDE1-1
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide1">voltar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide1-2">SLIDE1-2
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide1">voltar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2-1">SLIDE2-1
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide2">voltar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2-2">SLIDE2-2
      <a href="#" data-target=".slide2">voltar</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Diego é exatamente isso ! Agradeço o tempo dedicado à resposta

Comment: Gostei do seu script. Ele é mais complexo, mas fica facil de alterar. Eu tentei responder de forma mais simples.

Comment: @RafaelMarcos No caso, eu gosto de manter bem separado o JS do HTML, gosto mais desse tipo de organização. Em comparação com seu código a lógica foi a mesma, adiciona o evento onclick, esconde todos por uma classe e faz a busca por um seletor. :)

Answer (score 1):

Vou explicar usando javascript com o Jquery. Seguindo a logica desse exemplo, você consegue colocar quandos divs(slides) quiser. Ao chamar a function ExibirSlide, você deve passar o ID do slide alvo:

```js
        function ExibirSlide(id)
        {
            $(".slide").hide(); // Esconde todos os slides
            $('#' + id).show(); // Exibe o slide alvo
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="divSlideMain" class="slide">MAIN
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide1')">slide1</a>
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide2')">slide2</a>
        </div>
        <!-- second layer -->
        <div id="divSlide1" class="slide" style="display:none;">SLIDE1
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide1')">slide1</a>
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlideMain')">slide Main</a>
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide2')">slide2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="divSlide2" class="slide" style="display:none;">SLIDE2
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlideMain')">slide Main</a>
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide1')">slide1</a>
          <a href="#" onclick="ExibirSlide('divSlide2')">slide2</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```